# Append row to CSV adding header as a row

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have the following code which I am using to create and add a new row to a csv file.

```
def calcPrice(data):


  fieldnames = ["ReferenceID","clientName","Date","From","To","Rate","Price"]
  with open('rec2.csv', 'a') as csvfile:

    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(data)

  return
```

However, it as the header as a new row as well. How can I prevent this?
[image]

Comment: What happens if you leave out the writer.writeheader() row?

Answer (score 2):

The `writeheader` method writes a header row, so it should only be used on an empty file.

You should first test whether the file was or not empty and only write the header line on an empty file:

```
import os
...
  with open('rec2.csv', 'a') as csvfile:

    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    if 0 == os.lseek(csvfile, 0, os.SEEK_END):
      writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: I'm getting this error 

TypeError: an integer is required (got type _io.TextIOWrapper)